# Prevent tab into WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I would like to prevent tabbing into a read-only Microsoft data grid in WPF.
I set IsTabStop to False, but I can still tab into the data grid.
Any ideas?

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid
    IsReadOnly="True"
    IsTabStop="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridData, Mode=OneWay}" >
</WpfToolkit:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It helps, if you add this line to your datagrid xaml:

KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"

Comment: Was looking to disable tabbing into child controls under a grid and this seems to work as well.